# Value of a specific line of RichTextBox not changing

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am trying to do very simple thing which should work but unfortunately its not working.

I have a `RichTextBox` component on my `Winform`.
I am trying to change text value of some lines of the `RichTextBox` but its not changing the value. Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if(richTextBox1.Lines[i] == "ok")
            {
                richTextBox1.Lines[i] = "Done";
            }
        }
    }
```

I put break point and I notice that it executes

`richTextBox1.Lines[i] = "Done";`

But it does not change the value at all.
Can anyone explain it? Why its not modifying the value?
Is there way to change/modify the value as per Line?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN ([TextBoxBase.Lines Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines in the TextBox. To get a writable collection of lines, use code similar to the following: textBox1.Lines = new string[] { "abcd" };

so you better go for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (richTextBox1.Lines[i] == "ok")
    {
        string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
        lines[i] = "done";
        richTextBox1.Lines = lines;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: another way of doing this (that I do not recommend though):

```
string line = richTextBox1.Lines[i]; 
richTextBox1.Find(line);
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "done";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. But what if for larger text? I mean if the `RichTexBox` has larger document loaded. Will not be this a performance issue?

Comment: i don't think there's performance issues and there's no other fair way doing it (since it is a read-only copy of the lines)... but i've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks I think this one is better approach.